# maven sonar problem

Tags: maven-2, ant, sonarqube

I want to use sonar for analysis but i can't get any data in localhost:9000

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>KIS</artifactId>
  <groupId>KIS</groupId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                <property name="runtime_classpath" refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>
                <property name="test_classpath" refid="maven.test.classpath"/>
                <property name="plugin_classpath" refid="maven.plugin.classpath"/>
                <ant antfile="${basedir}/build.xml">
                  <target name="maven-compile"/>
                </ant>
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

output when running sonar: jar file is empty

```
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1250 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory J:\ostalo_6i\KIS deploy\ANT\src\test\resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] [jar:jar {execution: default-jar}]
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: J:\ostalo_6i\KIS deploy\ANT\target\KIS-1.0.jar
[INFO] [install:install {execution: default-install}]
[INFO] Installing J:\ostalo_6i\KIS deploy\ANT\target\KIS-1.0.jar to C:\Documents and Settings\MitjaG\.m2\repository\KIS\KIS\1.0\KIS-1.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - KIS:KIS:jar:1.0
[INFO]    task-segment: [sonar:sonar] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [sonar:sonar {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Sonar host: http://localhost:9000
[INFO] Sonar version: 2.1.2
[INFO] [sonar-core:internal {execution: default-internal}]
[INFO]  Database dialect class org.sonar.api.database.dialect.Oracle
[INFO]  -------------  Analyzing Unnamed - KIS:KIS:jar:1.0
[INFO]  Selected quality profile : KIS, language=java
[INFO]  Configure maven plugins...
[INFO]  Sensor SquidSensor...
[INFO]  Sensor SquidSensor done: 16 ms
[INFO]  Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
[INFO]  Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 0 ms
[INFO]  Sensor AsynchronousMeasuresSensor...
[INFO]  Sensor AsynchronousMeasuresSensor done: 15 ms
[INFO]  Sensor SurefireSensor...
[INFO]  parsing J:\ostalo_6i\KIS deploy\ANT\target\surefire-reports
[INFO]  Sensor SurefireSensor done: 47 ms
[INFO]  Sensor ProfileSensor...
[INFO]  Sensor ProfileSensor done: 16 ms
[INFO]  Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
[INFO]  Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO]  Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
[INFO]  Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 31 ms
[INFO]  Sensor CpdSensor...
[INFO]  Sensor CpdSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO]  Sensor Maven dependencies...
[INFO]  Sensor Maven dependencies done: 16 ms
[INFO]  Execute decorators...
[INFO]  ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000
[INFO]  Database optimization...
[INFO]  Database optimization done: 172 ms
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6 minutes 16 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 11 08:28:26 CEST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/43M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

any idea why, i successfully compile with maven ant plugin java project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven doesn't compile anything and is building an empty jar here (*No sources to compile*, *No tests to run*, *JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!*) so, while Sonar is processing it, there is actually nothing to analyze.

Actually, I don't think that wrapping an Ant build into a Maven project is enough for Sonar, Sonar won't discover your source and output directory. According to [Non-Maven projects (sonar light mode)](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Java+Projects#AnalyzingJavaProjects-NonMavenprojects%28sonarlightmode%29), you'll have to declare the source and output directory in a minimal `pom.xml` (and build your project prior to running Sonar).

Answer (score 0):

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-178

This will help u..

Comment: hmm i am using oracle DB not postgre

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you started the sonar server? You might check if it is still running.

I also see little correlation between the POM and the question and the runtimes in the output suggest that you have either an exceptionally fast computer or it is not doing anything.

I would first make sure you have some classes and unit tests which compile/test/install normally, before trying to get something into/from Sonar.

Comment: yes sonar is working. Do i have to specify where my project classess are. Can't sonar see from maven ant when compiling java sorce code?